# Damaged carbon fibre

Tags: road-bike, chain, bottom-bracket, carbon, damage

My chain dropped and got stuck in my bottom bracket while I was going uphill. I think the force from the pedal stroke damaged the carbon fibre. Wondering what is recommended when something like this happens?

Comment: For any advice here to matter, we need to see pics of the damage.  Without that we're really just guessing it's anything from a cosmetic scratch though to the chain cut the BB shell like a chainsaw.  Are you interested in why the chain dropped?